# GLM com a normal multivariada

Tags: r

Existe alguma função que faça GLM com a função de distribuição de probabilidade Normal Multivariada?

A forma de escrever a formula será igual função glm(), i.e. `y~.` , ou terá alguma particularidade?

Comment: você diz quando seu `y` é multivariado?

Comment: Pensei que poderia existir algo parecido com a função zeroinfl (Package ‘pscl’) onde se escreve `zeroinfl(y ~ . | .)` . Já no caso da normal multivariada cada mi teria sua propria formula.